# how can display older custom post outside the loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have some custom post in my page from a specific category. i set the post per page 3. now i want to see the older post when i click the more link. but the more link not in the loop.it is on the above of the loop. so how can i link to that more button so that i can see older post.

```
<!-- Form Around The World -->
<div class="from_around_the_world">
    <h2><?php echo get_the_category_by_id(2); ?></h2>
    <a class="common_style_more post_more" href="">More<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        // custom post query for catagoris
        $world_news = new WP_Query('cat=2'); 
        /* Post Query */
        if($world_news->have_posts()):
            while($world_news->have_posts()): $world_news->the_post();
            ?>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="single_around_the_world">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail');?></a>
                        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                        <p><?php echo excerpt('15'); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             <?php
             endwhile;

        else:
            echo "There is no post";
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- Form Around The World -->
```